# Mandatory Consent for Admob User Messaging Platform

Tags: android, admob, gdprconsentform, user-messaging-platform

I switched from the deprecated GDPR Consent Library to the new User Messaging Platform, and used the code as stated in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/admob/ump/android/quick-start).

I noticed that when the user clicks on *Manage Options* then *Confirm choices*, ads will stop displaying altogether (*Ad failed to load, no ad config*), and I can't find anyway to check if the user didn't consent to the use of personal data.

This is problematic as my app relies purely on ads, and I will be losing money if ads don't show up, so I want to make it mandatory for users to consent to the use of their personal data, otherwise the app should be unusable.

I have made a test project on [Github](https://github.com/hiddeneyes02/GDPR-Consent-Test) so everyone can test this behavior. If you are not using an emulator, then you need to change the "TEST_DEVICE_ID" to yours.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The UMP writes its output to some attributes in `SharedPreferences`, outlined [here](https://github.com/InteractiveAdvertisingBureau/GDPR-Transparency-and-Consent-Framework/blob/master/TCFv2/IAB%20Tech%20Lab%20-%20CMP%20API%20v2.md#in-app-details). You can write some helper methods to query these attributes to find out what level of ad consent the user has given or whether the user is EEA or not, but you will need to look at more than just the `VendorConsents` string.

There are generally 5 attributes you will want to look for to determine whether ads will be served:

- `IABTCF_gdprApplies` - An integer (0 or 1) indicating whether the user is in the EEA
- `IABTCF_PurposeConsents` - A string of 0's and 1's up to 10 entries long indicating whether the user provided consent for the 10 different purposes
- `IABTCF_PurposeLegitimateInterests` - A string of 0's and 1's up to 10 entries long indicating whether the app has legitimate interest for the 10 different purposes
- `IABTCF_VendorConsents` - A string of 0s and 1s that is arbitrarily long, indicating whether a given vendor has been given consent for the previously mentioned purposes. Each vendor has an ID indicating their position in the string. For example Google's ID is 755, so if Google has been given consent then the 755th character in this string would be a "1". The full vendor list is available [here](https://iabeurope.eu/vendor-list-tcf/).
- `IABTCF_VendorLegitimateInterests` - Similar to the vendor consent string, except that it indicates if the vendor has legitimate interest for the previously indicated purposes.

Per the Google documentation [here](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/9760862?hl=en&ref_topic=9756841) there are really only a few practical outcomes from the UMP Funding Choices form with respect to serving ads:

1. The user clicked "Consent To All" - the strings above will be all 1's and personalized ads will be shown
2. The user clicked "Consent To None" - no ads will be shown at all
3. The user clicked "Manage" and selected storage consent (Purpose 1) and scrolled through the giant list of non-alphabetically listed vendors to also select "Google" - non-personalized ads will be shown
4. The user clicked "Manage" and did anything less than the prior step (e.g. selected storage and basic ads but didn't manually select Google from the vendor list) - again, no ads will be shown at all

This is a pretty non-ideal set of options, since #3 is extremely unlikely to ever occur and #2 and #4 result in the user getting an ad-free app without paying. For all practical purposes, this has removed the "non-personalized ads" option that was in the legacy consent SDK (and the option to purchase the ad-free app) and replaced it with simply disabling ads entirely.

I've written a few helper methods to at least let you query what the user actually selected and act accordingly.

```
fun isGDPR(): Boolean {
    val prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(applicationContext)
    val gdpr = prefs.getInt("IABTCF_gdprApplies", 0)
    return gdpr == 1
}

fun canShowAds(): Boolean {
    val prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(applicationContext)

    //https://github.com/InteractiveAdvertisingBureau/GDPR-Transparency-and-Consent-Framework/blob/master/TCFv2/IAB%20Tech%20Lab%20-%20CMP%20API%20v2.md#in-app-details
    //https://support.google.com/admob/answer/9760862?hl=en&ref_topic=9756841

    val purposeConsent = prefs.getString("IABTCF_PurposeConsents", "") ?: ""
    val vendorConsent = prefs.getString("IABTCF_VendorConsents","") ?: ""
    val vendorLI = prefs.getString("IABTCF_VendorLegitimateInterests","") ?: ""
    val purposeLI = prefs.getString("IABTCF_PurposeLegitimateInterests","") ?: ""

    val googleId = 755
    val hasGoogleVendorConsent = hasAttribute(vendorConsent, index=googleId)
    val hasGoogleVendorLI = hasAttribute(vendorLI, index=googleId)

    // Minimum required for at least non-personalized ads
    return hasConsentFor(listOf(1), purposeConsent, hasGoogleVendorConsent)
            && hasConsentOrLegitimateInterestFor(listOf(2,7,9,10), purposeConsent, purposeLI, hasGoogleVendorConsent, hasGoogleVendorLI)

}

fun canShowPersonalizedAds(): Boolean {
    val prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(applicationContext)

    //https://github.com/InteractiveAdvertisingBureau/GDPR-Transparency-and-Consent-Framework/blob/master/TCFv2/IAB%20Tech%20Lab%20-%20CMP%20API%20v2.md#in-app-details
    //https://support.google.com/admob/answer/9760862?hl=en&ref_topic=9756841

    val purposeConsent = prefs.getString("IABTCF_PurposeConsents", "") ?: ""
    val vendorConsent = prefs.getString("IABTCF_VendorConsents","") ?: ""
    val vendorLI = prefs.getString("IABTCF_VendorLegitimateInterests","") ?: ""
    val purposeLI = prefs.getString("IABTCF_PurposeLegitimateInterests","") ?: ""

    val googleId = 755
    val hasGoogleVendorConsent = hasAttribute(vendorConsent, index=googleId)
    val hasGoogleVendorLI = hasAttribute(vendorLI, index=googleId)

    return hasConsentFor(listOf(1,3,4), purposeConsent, hasGoogleVendorConsent)
            && hasConsentOrLegitimateInterestFor(listOf(2,7,9,10), purposeConsent, purposeLI, hasGoogleVendorConsent, hasGoogleVendorLI)
}

// Check if a binary string has a "1" at position "index" (1-based)
private fun hasAttribute(input: String, index: Int): Boolean {
    return input.length >= index && input[index-1] == '1'
}

// Check if consent is given for a list of purposes
private fun hasConsentFor(purposes: List<Int>, purposeConsent: String, hasVendorConsent: Boolean): Boolean {
    return purposes.all { p -> hasAttribute(purposeConsent, p)} && hasVendorConsent
}

// Check if a vendor either has consent or legitimate interest for a list of purposes
private fun hasConsentOrLegitimateInterestFor(purposes: List<Int>, purposeConsent: String, purposeLI: String, hasVendorConsent: Boolean, hasVendorLI: Boolean): Boolean {
    return purposes.all { p ->
            (hasAttribute(purposeLI, p) && hasVendorLI) ||
            (hasAttribute(purposeConsent, p) && hasVendorConsent)
    }
}
```

**Note** `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences` is *not* deprecated - you just need to make sure to include the androidx import (`import androidx.preference.PreferenceManager`). If you include the wrong one (`import android.preference.PreferenceManager`), it will be marked as deprecated.

**Edit: Example integration**

Here is an example implementation of a `ConsentHelper` method for managing calling the UMP SDK and handling the results. This would be called on app load (e.g. in the activity `onCreate`) with

```kotlin
ConsentHelper.obtainConsentAndShow(activity) {
    // add your code to load ads here
}
```

This handles waiting to initialize the MobileAds SDK until after obtaining consent, and then uses a callback to begin loading ads after the consent workflow is complete.

```kotlin
object ConsentHelper {
    private var isMobileAdsInitializeCalled = AtomicBoolean(false)
    private var showingForm = false
    private var showingWarning = false

    private fun initializeMobileAdsSdk(context: Context) {
        if (isMobileAdsInitializeCalled.getAndSet(true)) {
            return
        }

        // Initialize the Google Mobile Ads SDK.
        MobileAds.initialize(context)
    }

    // Called from app settings to determine whether to 
    // show a button so the user can launch the dialog
    fun isUpdateConsentButtonRequired(context: Context) : Boolean {
        val consentInformation = UserMessagingPlatform.getConsentInformation(context)
        return consentInformation.privacyOptionsRequirementStatus ==
                ConsentInformation.PrivacyOptionsRequirementStatus.REQUIRED
    }

    // Called when the user clicks the button to launch
    // the CMP dialog and change their selections
    fun updateConsent(context: Activity) {
        UserMessagingPlatform.showPrivacyOptionsForm(context) { error ->
            val ci = UserMessagingPlatform.getConsentInformation(context)
            handleConsentResult(context, ci, loadAds = {})
        }
    }

    // Called from onCreate or on app load somewhere
    fun obtainConsentAndShow(context: AppCompatActivity, loadAds: ()->Unit) {

        val params = if( BuildConfig.DEBUG ) {
            val debugSettings = ConsentDebugSettings.Builder(context)
                .setDebugGeography(ConsentDebugSettings.DebugGeography.DEBUG_GEOGRAPHY_EEA)
                .addTestDeviceHashedId("YOUR_DEVICE_ID") // Get ID from Logcat
                .build()
            ConsentRequestParameters
                .Builder()
                .setTagForUnderAgeOfConsent(false)
                .setConsentDebugSettings(debugSettings)
                .build()
        }
        else {
            ConsentRequestParameters
                .Builder()
                .setTagForUnderAgeOfConsent(false)
                .build()
        }

        val ci = UserMessagingPlatform.getConsentInformation(context)
        ci.requestConsentInfoUpdate(
            context,
            params,
            {   // Load and show the consent form. Add guard to prevent showing form more than once at a time.
                if( showingForm ) return@requestConsentInfoUpdate

                showingForm = true
                UserMessagingPlatform.loadAndShowConsentFormIfRequired(context) { error: FormError? ->
                    showingForm = false
                    handleConsentResult(context, ci, loadAds)
                }
            },
            { error ->
                // Consent gathering failed.
                Log.w("AD_HANDLER", "${error.errorCode}: ${error.message}")
            })

        // Consent has been gathered already, load ads
        if( ci.canRequestAds() ) {
            initializeMobileAdsSdk(context.applicationContext)
            loadAds()
        }
    }

    private fun handleConsentResult(context: Activity, ci: ConsentInformation, loadAds: ()->Unit) {

        // Consent has been gathered.
        if( ci.canRequestAds() ) {
            initializeMobileAdsSdk(context.applicationContext)
            logConsentChoices(context)
            loadAds()
        }
        else {
            // This is an error state - should never get here
            logConsentChoices(context)
        }
    }

    private fun logConsentChoices(context: Activity) {
        // After completing the consent workflow, check the
        // strings in SharedPreferences to see what they
        // consented to and act accordingly
        val canShow = canShowAds(context)
        val isEEA = isGDPR(context)

        // Check what level of consent the user actually provided
        println("TEST:    user consent choices")
        println("TEST:      is EEA = $isEEA")
        println("TEST:      can show ads = $canShow")
        println("TEST:      can show personalized ads = ${canShowPersonalizedAds(context)}")

        if( !isEEA ) return

        // handle user choice, activate trial mode, etc

    }
}
```

Comment: The global list of vendor IDs can be found here: https://vendor-list.consensu.org/v2/vendor-list.json

Comment: It seems apps still using legacy content SDK will only get non personalized apps now!?

Comment: This is awesome, thanks Tyler for the work.  

The other thing I noticed is that in the UI, the user also has option to turn OFF legitimate interests for the vendor, which makes no sense to me at all.  

If user clicks "Manage" and then selects storage consent (purpose 1) but turns off Google Advertising legitimate interest, no ads display.  Why would a user have a say over what Google's legitimate interests are?

Completely ridiculous.

If I select

Comment: The links to the list of vendors seems to have changed. There is an interactive list where you can search here: https://iabeurope.eu/vendor-list-tcf/

Comment: @Frozax, thanks for letting me know. I updated the link in the answer

Comment: It seems that Google had added a new limited mode that only requires LI(2,7,9,10). ref: https://developers.google.com/admob/android/privacy/ad-serving-modes

Comment: I don't understand why IABTCF_PublisherConsent seems to be completely irrelevant (corresponds to the "Site or app" section of the consent dialog). I mean if you don't allow the app to store information this implies that the GMA SDK is also not allowed to do that, right?

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking. The TCF string is used by GMA SDK and its partners to decide what it's allowed to use/store/do. If there is no consent for storage, then it can't even store the necessary cookie for serving non-personalized ads. The "IABTCF_PublisherConsent" contains the user's choices from the dialog (shown more granularly on the second screen).

Comment: Also this "storage consent" from the UMP dialog is somehow distinct from the user already consenting to install your app on their device by going to the app store and installing it, which lets the app write files to the device already...

Comment: @Noice2D Yes, theoretically "limited mode" exists, but what I read everywhere is that in practice this will also mean no ads (error 3 when requesting adds).

Comment: I failed to make `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences` work, even with AndroidX when building an `aar` library and using it as a plugin in Godot. It cr.ps out at runtime when calling it.

What worked for me, in the end was:
`SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(context.getPackageName() + "_preferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);`

No need for AndroidX (even though minSDK == 19), and it works without issues.

Comment: Probably missing `implementation("androidx.preference:preference-ktx:1.2.1")` in your gradle file?

Comment: @TylerV Thank you sincerely for this solution! It's incredibly helpful. I have a question about its longevity: is it considered future-proof? If not, would you kindly commit to updating this answer in the event of changes? This way, we can return to this thread and adapt our code accordingly.

Comment: thanks for the useful information Tyler! What is the minimum requirements for personalized ads? What purposes and vendors must the user click? Thanks!

Comment: According to Google even in the absence of purpose 1, limited ads will be served! see the link https://support.google.com/admob/answer/10105530?hl=en&ref_topic=10303737&sjid=6579090329600818894-NA

Comment: They have been promoting the "limited ads" for awhile now, but if you try it and start reading their fine print you will find that you can only ever server limited ads if you had mediation set up with certain waterfall settings. If you just use AdMob without mediation, you still don't get any ads showing up. But don't take my word for it - try it out. Maybe they've fixed it since the original rollout. re: minimum required for personalized ads - that's in the code in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround for this, but this is no final official solution.

It seems that if a user consented to Personalized ads, a string in `SharedPreferences`, which key is **IABTCF_VendorConsents**, will contain ones and zeros corresponding to some vendors (I think). If he didn't consent, this string will be equal to **0**.

```
private val sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(appContext)
fun consentedToPersonalizedAds() = sp.getString("IABTCF_VendorConsents", null) != "0"
```