# Parsing the Google GDRP Consent string in Swift/IOS

Tags: android, ios, admob, gdprconsentform, ump

I have been trying to prepare for the upcoming AdMob mandate to support EU GDPR regulations in January 2024. As it turns out, if the User opts not to consent or uses "Manage Options" but doesn't toggle the correct combinations of options, no ads will be filled by AdMob.

I was able to find an Android solution to parsing the UMP Consent String in order to determine if my AdMob ads would be supported based on the User's responses to the consent form. That code is here:

https://itnext.io/android-admob-consent-with-ump-personalized-or-non-personalized-ads-in-eea-3592e192ec90

I was able to convert those helper methods to Swift for IOS and want to share that code here:

```
    //MARK: GDPR: Parsing Google UMP Consent String
    
    // https://support.google.com/admanager/answer/9681920?hl=en
    // https://itnext.io/android-admob-consent-with-ump-personalized-or-non-personalized-ads-in-eea-3592e192ec90

    func fetchUserDefault(forKey: String) -> String
    {
        let prefs = UserDefaults.standard

        if let value = prefs.string(forKey: forKey)
        {
            return value
        }
        else
        {
            return "";
        }
    }
    
    func canShowAds() -> Bool
    {
        let purposeConsent = self.fetchUserDefault(forKey: "IABTCF_PurposeConsents");
        let vendorConsent = self.fetchUserDefault(forKey: "IABTCF_VendorConsents");
        let vendorLI = self.fetchUserDefault(forKey: "IABTCF_VendorLegitimateInterests");
        let purposeLI = self.fetchUserDefault(forKey: "IABTCF_PurposeLegitimateInterests");

        /*
            The end user grants Google consent to:
         
                Store and/or access information on a device (Purpose 1)
         
            Legitimate interest (or consent, where a publisher configures their CMP to request it) is established for Google to:
         
                Select basic ads (Purpose 2)
                Measure ad performance (Purpose 7)
                Apply market research to generate audience insights (Purpose 9)
                Develop and improve products (Purpose 10)
         
                For Personalized Ads:
         
                Create a Personalized Ad Profile (Purpose 3)
                Select Personal Ads (Purpose 4)
         
            MUST provide consent to Google Advertising Products in Vendor Preferences List (not alphabetized) in order to get ads from AdMob
                
        */

        let googleId = 755;
        let hasGoogleVendorConsent = self.hasAttribute(vendorConsent, googleId);
        let hasGoogleVendorLI = self.hasAttribute(vendorLI, googleId);

        var indexes = [Int]();
        indexes.Add(1);

        var indexesLI = [Int]();
        indexesLI.Add(2);
        indexesLI.Add(7);
        indexesLI.Add(9);
        indexesLI.Add(10);

        return self.hasConsentFor(indexes, purposeConsent, hasGoogleVendorConsent)
        && self.hasConsentOrLegitimateInterestFor(indexesLI, purposeConsent, purposeLI, hasGoogleVendorConsent, hasGoogleVendorLI);
    }

    func canShowPersonalizedAds() -> Bool
    {
        let purposeConsent = self.fetchUserDefault(forKey: "IABTCF_PurposeConsents");
        let vendorConsent = self.fetchUserDefault(forKey: "IABTCF_VendorConsents");
        let vendorLI = self.fetchUserDefault(forKey: "IABTCF_VendorLegitimateInterests");
        let purposeLI = self.fetchUserDefault(forKey: "IABTCF_PurposeLegitimateInterests");

        let googleId = 755;
        let hasGoogleVendorConsent = self.hasAttribute(vendorConsent, googleId);
        let hasGoogleVendorLI = self.hasAttribute(vendorLI, googleId);

        var indexes = [Int]();
        indexes.Add(1);
        indexes.Add(3);
        indexes.Add(4);

        var indexesLI = [Int]();
        indexesLI.Add(2);
        indexesLI.Add(7);
        indexesLI.Add(9);
        indexesLI.Add(10);

        return self.hasConsentFor(indexes, purposeConsent, hasGoogleVendorConsent)
        && self.hasConsentOrLegitimateInterestFor(indexesLI, purposeConsent, purposeLI, hasGoogleVendorConsent, hasGoogleVendorLI);
    }

    private func hasConsentFor(_ indexes: [Int], _ purposeConsent: String, _ hasVendorConsent: Bool) -> Bool
    {
        for p in indexes
        {
            if (!self.hasAttribute(purposeConsent, p))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        
        return hasVendorConsent;
    }

    private func hasAttribute(_ input: String, _ index: Int) -> Bool
    {
        let characters = input.toCharacterArray() ///extension method: uses "return Array(self)"
        if (characters.count < index-1)
        {
            return false
        }
        
        let indexValue = characters[index-1]
        
        return (indexValue == "1")
    }

    private func hasConsentOrLegitimateInterestFor(_ indexes: [Int], _ purposeConsent: String, _ purposeLI: String, _ hasVendorConsent: Bool, _ hasVendorLI: Bool) -> Bool
    {
        for p in indexes
        {
            let purposeAndVendorLI = self.hasAttribute(purposeLI, p) && hasVendorLI;
            let purposeConsentAndVendorConsent = self.hasAttribute(purposeConsent, p) && hasVendorConsent;
            
            let isOk = purposeAndVendorLI || purposeConsentAndVendorConsent;
            
            if (!isOk)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Now that I am able to parse the results of the consent string to determine if my app will be able to deliver AdMob ads, I could use some help guidance on whether anyone knows if it violates any store policie (App Store or Google Play) to prevent Users from using my app should their configuration effectively disable my ads?

Comment: I came across this post while continuing to work on my solution. It appears this code must have been the basis of the Android code I posted (based on dates) AND includes an additional helper to check if GDPR was required.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65351543/how-to-implement-ump-sdk-correctly-for-eu-consent/68310602#68310602

Comment: Store policy questions are generally off-topic on StackOverflow. Also, it is more likely to violate GDPR policy than app store policy. Quoting from [here](https://gdpr.eu/gdpr-consent-requirements/): "“Freely given” consent essentially means you have not cornered the data subject into agreeing to you using their data. For one thing, that means you cannot require consent to data processing as a condition of using the service.". I find it absurd that them seem to be requiring you to give away your intellectual property for free, and I don't know if that is an official policy or not.

Comment: And yes, all these random Medium posts about this are just copying my two StackOverflow posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65351543/how-to-implement-ump-sdk-correctly-for-eu-consent/68310602#68310602) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69307205/mandatory-consent-for-admob-user-messaging-platform/70324431#70324431)

Comment: Glad you saw my post, Tyler. You deserve credit for the code you shared. It is extremely valuable and will be needed by many in January 2024

Comment: Thank you @danny - this is extremely helpful. As per Tyler V, I suspect it would violate GDPR policy to prevent usage of App. It is indeed absurd.  One option that may be comply with "freely given" is to always pop up the GDPR on app startup if canShowAds == false, using UMPConsentInformation.sharedInstance.reset(). Note though that it does say in the GoogleDocs: "Caution: This method is intended to be used for testing purposes only. You shouldn't call reset in production code." - https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/privacy#reset_consent_state (It does say shouldn't though, not mustn't :))