# Admob Consent new form, let users disable Ads completely

Tags: android, flutter, admob, gdprconsentform

I am trying to Add a consent form using  Google User Messaging (UMP) SDK. everything is working well, but if the user chose anything different than "Consent" they will not see any Ads at all even backfill ads!

This is really alarming, because users in EEA & UK will be able to disable Ads easily.

What should I do? at least the backfill Ads should work!

Did this happened to anyone before? and how did you fix it?

Comment: There is no choice but to wait for the admob team to fix it.

Comment: @regenin are you facing the same problem?

Comment: everyone suffers from this problem. If you look at the Admob forum you will see complaints.

Comment: This has been raised in [thread1](https://groups.google.com/g/google-admob-ads-sdk/c/MkX6n49Z3yU/m/ACq5fvJHBAAJ) and [thread2](https://groups.google.com/g/google-admob-ads-sdk/c/UcveWmtBm4Q/m/moh9hvBVCwAJ). In thread1, a google employee says that they’ve opened a feature ticket and that we should look out for updates to the ads blog [here](https://ads-developers.googleblog.com/search/label/admob).... So far no news....

Answer (score 1):

You have three options: use another ad providing system, simply wait for the Admob team to fix it, or use this related post ([Mandatory Consent for Admob User Messaging Platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69307205/mandatory-consent-for-admob-user-messaging-platform?rq=1)). I personally do not use flutter or Admob, so this is the best I have, and the comments on the question you posted agree with waiting for Admob to fix the issue.
I believe:

[image: There is nothing we can do with Admob]