# AdMob not showing test ads when user rejects GDPR consent

Tags: admob

I've successfully added AdMob SDK to my mobile app, for showing both interstitial videos and rewarded ads.
When the GDPR consent form is shown, if the user accepts with consent, everything continues to work great.
However, if the user opens the "Manage options" in the consent form, and removes the consent for everything, the ads just stop loading, returning the "No Fill" error (error code 3).
But I'm still using test ads, so it doesn't make sense having a No Fill. The documentation says there will always be an ad filled with Test ads.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

There is something wrong with consent form using Google User Messaging (UMP) SDK.
[Check this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77503802/admob-consent-new-form-let-users-disable-ads-completely).  Also check [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/g/google-admob-ads-sdk/c/xRaBKayC_80)

Hopefully Google will fix it soon